# iphone 3.5 and 4 issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

i was making an application is ios6 but i have to make it compatible for ios5 too. i made weak link to the libraries and they are working fine but one issue arises and i still not solve it. the problem is regarding iphone 5 and iphone 4 sizes. i had some questions:

1. in view under xib what i should pick view size iphone 3.5 or iphone 4?
2. if i place in buttons and other controls according to 4 size than they goes out when i run it on iphone 4 and vice versa?
3. should i need to make two xibs to overcome it?
4. or is there any other method which will resize my view and make it compatible for iphone 4 and 5?

**EDIT**
iam making application on ios6 and i want my application to run on both iphone 4 and 5.

thanks .

Comment: iam making app on ios6 and i want my application to run on both iphone 4 and 5.

Comment: Then make sure you turn off "autolayout" and then you can use the "autoresizing" options/masks that I discuss in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you don't have to worry about this because iOS can move your controls around for you using either:

- **Auto sizing**: If supporting iOS versions prior to 6, use the auto sizing masks (sometimes affectionately called "springs and struts", and when accessing programmatically, it's called the `autoresizingMask`) so that everything moves arounds appropriately. So select the "size inspector" and adjust the "autosizing" masks:

  [image: auto sizing]
- **Autolayout**: If you're developing an iOS 6 and above app, you can also use the new the "autolayout". See [Cocoa Auto Layout Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2) which has tons of relevant links. Also see the [Xcode 4 Users Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/030-Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH6-SW56).
- **Turn autolayout on and off:** If you want to develop an iOS 4/5 compatible app, you may need to turn off "autolayout". If so, go to Interface Builder, click somewhere on the background, select the "file inspector" in the right panel, and examine/change the "Use Autolayout" flag.

  [image: turn off autolayout]

I'd suggest designing for the 3.5" screen. And let it resize or move your controls for the 4" screen.

Comment: but I'm not the one who created this question. Can't help. I up-voted your answer, it's all I can do

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were. Thanks just the same.